# Hide and show elements with v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Here is my fiddle : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jt0nnLpp/)

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    modules: ['abc', 'def']
  }
})
```

How can I hide/show with v-if based on the values found in an array ( modules[] ) ?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least a couple of options to manage this, which I'll describe here. The first is a simple check inside of `v-if` to see if the item is contained within `modules`. For example:

```
<div class="abc box" v-if="modules.indexOf('abc') >= 0">abc</div>
<div class="def box" v-if="modules.indexOf('def') >= 0">def</div>
...
```

This is a little bit crude and not great from a maintenance or performance perspective. Another option would be to use the `modules` array as the source for your collection of `div`s, using [`v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html). For example:

```
<div class="box" v-for="module in modules" :class="module">{{ module }}</div>
```

There's a few things to note here:

1. `v-for` looks directly at the `modules` array to determine the number of divs to render.
2. The value in the array is used both as the text for the div (`{{ module }}`) and as one of the classes (`:class="module"`).
3. The class `box` is always applied, using the standard `class` attribute. The combination of this and the `:class` binding end up with e.g. `abc box` as the class list.

Here's a working example demonstrating the `v-for` approach.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    modules: ['abc', 'def']
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  background: #444;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.6/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="box" v-for="module in modules" :class="module">{{ module }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I attach an @click="goTo(module)"  to these divs as well? Will the 'module' param hold the value of array elements from modules[] ? I need this @click because I will be defining the routes based on click of the divs

Comment: Yes, `module` will refer to the correct item within your array, so this works fine.